# Single status field on entity, or flags

Tags: database-design, entity

I am designing a database that will keep a number of different entities. One table for each entity, for instance `Post`, `Comment`, `Referral`, `Company` ...

Each entity will likely have some status associated with it, such as `submitted`, `draft`, `withdrawn`, `rejected` and any other status I have yet to think of.

A simple solution would be a single `status` column on each entity. However, a valid entity state may be both `submitted` **and** `rejected` at the same time (or any other combination).

The immediate answer to the above is to create a columns for each status, kind of like a flag that is either true or false. However, this runs the risk of an entity having flags that are not compatible, i.e. `published` and `draft` <sub>(in theory you could publish a draft, but consider it not possible for the sake of the example)</sub>

- Will the application logic simply have to deal with it?
- Do I somehow group the different possible status flags into groups and a single column?

Initially this sounds to me like question that will receive an *it depends* type of answer. It could even come down to personal preference. **However**, these type of issues tend to have some known best-practices. Certainly most entities more or less end up with the same status flags that the logic can be re-used?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to create a column for each status, but you should absolutely define each column so that it logically will never need to contain more than a single status.

It sounds like you need to perform additional analysis. For instance, you could define "rejected" as having both been submitted and then subsequently rejected -- rejected being the latest status in a workflow.

Another approach would be to have two columns: one to represent the workflow status of creation through submission, and another to contain the result of the submission -- such as Under Review, On Hold, Accepted, or Rejected.

Either way, you need to perform additional analysis to determine which would better fit your needs. And the User Requirement should drive the analysis.

Comment: @bblue -- does this sufficiently answer the question? http://stackoverflow.com/users/1681418/bblue

Comment: @bblue -- Are you there? Please respond?